# Zend resolver could not resolve to a file

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've recently moved an application from one sever to another and am stuck with an issue. Its no longer working on the new server and I don't know why.

Any help greatly appreciated.

I believe the error to be:

```
    Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template &quot;application/command/fire-curl-request/index&quot;; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

module.config.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application;

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            //Add route delete a request.
            'delete-request' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/delete-request[/:requestId][/]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'requestId' => '[0-9]+'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'deleteRequest',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'change-status' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/change-status[/:requestId][/to/:active][/]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'requestId' => '[0-9]+',
                        'active' => '[0-9]+'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'changeStatus',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'create-new-request' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/create-new-request',
                    'constraints' => array(
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'createNewRequest',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'fire-curl-requests-web' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/fire-curl-requests',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller\Command',
                        'controller'    => 'FireCurlRequest',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'redirect' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/redirect',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller\Command',
                        'controller'    => 'FireCurlRequest',
                        'action'        => 'redirect',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'fire-curl-requests' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'fire-curl-requests',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller\Command',
                            'controller'    => 'FireCurlRequest',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        )
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class,
            'Application\Controller\Command\FireCurlRequest' => Controller\Command\FireCurlRequest::class
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

FireCurlRequest.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application\Controller\Command;

use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Stdlib\Parameters;
use Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

/**
 * Class IndexController
 * @package Application\Controller
 */
class FireCurlRequest extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $adapter = false;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $requestHeadersTable = 'request_headers';
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $requestSentTable = 'request_sent';

    /**
     * @return ViewModel
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {


        $requests = $this->getAllRequests();
        foreach ($requests as $request) {

            /** Check if already made nr of request is lower than the total allowed  */
            if ($request['request_count'] <= $request['sum']) {
                continue;
            }

            $requestStart = new \DateTime($request['modified']);

            $fromHour = $this->getStartHourForCurrentTime($requestStart);
            $toHour = new \DateTime('now');
            $sentThisHour = 0;
            $alreadySent = $this->getAlreadySentRequestForRequest($request['id']);

            foreach ($alreadySent as $sent) {
                if ($this->isBetweenDates($fromHour->format('Y-m-d H:i'), $toHour->format('Y-m-d H:i'), $sent['created'])) {
                    $sentThisHour += $sent['request_count_sent'];
                }
            }
            if ($request['request_hour_count'] >= $sentThisHour) {
                $leftToSentThisHour = $request['request_hour_count'] - $sentThisHour;
                $strtotimeToHour = strtotime($fromHour->format('Y-m-d H:i')) + 60*60;
                $currentstrtotime = strtotime('now');
                $secondsUntilHour = $strtotimeToHour - $currentstrtotime;
                $minutesLeft = (int)ceil(($secondsUntilHour / 60));

                $curlsToExecuteNow = ceil($leftToSentThisHour / $minutesLeft);
                $sentCurlRequest = 0;
                for ($i=1; $i<=$curlsToExecuteNow; $i++) {
                    /** Send curls */
                    $curlFlag = $this->doCurlRequest($request);
                    if ($curlFlag) {
                        $sentCurlRequest++;
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($sentCurlRequest)) {
                    $this->saveCurlRequests($request, $sentCurlRequest);
                }
            }
        }
        die('curl sent');
    }

    /**
     * @param $request
     * @param $sentCurlRequest
     * @return bool
     */
    public function saveCurlRequests($request, $sentCurlRequest)
    {
        try {
            $sql = new Sql($this->getAdapter());
            $sql->setTable($this->requestSentTable);
            $action = $sql->insert()
                ->values(array(
                    'request_header_id' => $request['id'],
                    'request_count_sent' =>  $sentCurlRequest
                ));
            $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($action);
            $statement->execute();
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $request
     * @return bool
     */
    public function doCurlRequest($request)
    {
        try {




            $ch = curl_init($request['request_url']);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://ihouseumail.com");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function redirectAction()
    {
        $url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
        header( 'Location:' . $url ) ;
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * @param $requestId
     * @return \Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface
     */
    private function getAlreadySentRequestForRequest($requestId)
    {
        $requests = array();
        $sql = new Sql($this->getAdapter());
        $select = $sql->select( $this->requestSentTable)
            ->where('request_header_id = ' . $requestId);
        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select) ;
        return $statement->execute();
    }

    /**
     * @param $startDate
     * @param $endDate
     * @param $dateToCheck
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isBetweenDates($startDate, $endDate, $dateToCheck)
    {
        if (($dateToCheck > $startDate) && ($dateToCheck < $endDate)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $requestStart
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartHourForCurrentTime($requestStart)
    {
        $nextHour = strtotime($requestStart->format('Y-m-d H:i')) + 60*60 ;
        $currentTime = strtotime('now');

        if ($currentTime > $nextHour) {
            $requestStart = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i', $nextHour));
            return $this->getStartHourForCurrentTime($requestStart);
        }
        return $requestStart;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAllRequests()
    {
        $requests = array();
        $sql = new Sql($this->getAdapter());
        $select = $sql->select( $this->requestHeadersTable)->where('active = 1');
        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select) ;
        $results = $statement->execute();
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $query = $this->getAdapter()->query('SELECT SUM(request_count_sent) as sum FROM request_sent WHERE request_header_id = ' . $result['id']);
            $sum = $query->execute()->next();
            $requestArray = array_merge($result, $sum);
            $requests[] = $requestArray;
        }
        return $requests;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|bool|object
     */
    private function getAdapter()
    {
        if (!$this->adapter) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        }
        return $this->adapter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `module/application/views/application/command/fire-curl-request/index.phtml` exist?

Comment: Nope 

I've got /public_html/module/Application/view/application/index/index.phtml?